# How to join figures from different codes in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have figures from three different codes in matlab, with the same axis.

How do I combine them in to one plot?

Is there a way to write a new script and reference a plot from another code?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a way you can change the three scripts to be functions? That way you can write a script which calls the three functions and plots the outputs on the same axis.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following three functions `p1()`, `p2()` and `p3()` which plot three different waveforms. Each function returns three handles for figure, plot and axes, respectively.

```
function [fig,plt, ax] = p1()

fig = figure;

t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 500);

plt = plot(t, sin(2*pi*2*t));
xlim([0 2*pi])

grid on

ax = gca;

end

function [fig, plt, ax] = p2()


fig = figure;

t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 500);

plt = plot(t, cos(2*pi*0.5*t));

xlim([0 2*pi])

grid on

ax  = gca;

end

function [fig, plt, ax] = p3()

fig = figure;

t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 500);

plt = plot(t, 2*exp(-0.5*t));

xlim([0 2*pi])

grid on

ax = gca;

end
```

These three functions create the following figures:
[image]

Then, by copying the `Children` attribute from each `axes` to a subplot handle on a new figure, you can merge the three independently generated graphs into one figure, as follows:

```
clear
close all

[f1, p1, ax1] = p1();
[f2, p2, ax2] = p2();
[f3, p3, ax3] = p3();

merge = figure;

sb1 = subplot(3,1,1);

copyobj(ax1.Children, sb1);

grid on

sb2 = subplot(3,1,2);

copyobj(ax2.Children, sb2);

grid on

sb3 = subplot(3,1,3);

copyobj(ax3.Children, sb3);

grid on
```

Outputting the following figure:

[image]

This is just a crude approach, however, it should give you a starting point.
Just to clarify, the `fig` and `plt` handles are only passed as an output in case you need to use their attributes.

Play around with this code and let me know if it works for you